# Is there a package to calculate the Long-Term-Average-Spectrum (LTAS) in Python?

Tags: python, audio, fft, wave

I search for a package similar to https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/55212-long-term-average-spectrum in Python 3.
I found https://homepage.univie.ac.at/christian.herbst/python/index.html#praatUtilDemo, however it does not seem to work with Python 3 and I could not get it running.
Also, I tried to implement it myself, but the spectrum looks strange.
My steps were:

1. get SPLs from my wave file.
2. divide audio sequence into 20 ms intervals (non-overlapping)
3. use numpy to calculate the Fourier transformation `timeframe = np.fft.rfft(timeframe-np.mean(timeframe))` for each timeframe.
4. use `np.abs(timeframe)` to process the imaginary part of the result.
5. calculate the mean spectrum over all intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Welch method can be used to calculate the averaged spectrum of a time series. It does what you intended to do in steps 2-5.

Checkout the SciPy signal package and the welch method:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.welch.html